# Sum By Color in cell array

Tags: vba

I am trying to perform a sum by colour I only need this to perform for one color and for the sum to be output to a single cell. Attached is the code I currently have which doesn't appear to be carrying the value of the cell correctly.

```
For j = 1 To nCols
    For i = 1 To nRows

        If Worksheets("LG").Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then

            vResult = ActiveCell.Value
        End If
            vResultf = vResultf + vResult
    Next i
Next j



Worksheets("Function Select").Range("B4").Value = vResultf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim c As Range, j, i, vResultf 

For j = 1 To nCols
    For i = 1 To nRows
        Set c = Worksheets("LG").Cells(i, j)
        If c.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then vResultf = vResultf + c.Value
    Next i
Next j

Worksheets("Function Select").Range("B4").Value = vResultf
```